# Change Python Path from Anaconda to Python 3 Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I have been trying to work in python recently but I've ran into a problem. I had to download Anaconda Navigator for a class so we could use the JupyterLab and JupyterNotebook software. While I do think that these programs are cool and helpful, I want to write scripts in the regular python software. When I download a new python library in the terminal(EX: pip3 install discord), the library will say it downloaded in the Anaconda Navigator files,

```
/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

and not the regular python IDLE/Shell. My question is how do I change this so that the downloaded libraries do not go to anaconda and only go to the regular python software.

Please let me know if you guys would like anymore info. Thank you!

Comment: You're probably using the `pip` that comes with Anaconda. Try to find the binary of your original `pip` and try installing a package from there. Once you confirm it installs to the right directory, you can just make sure that your $PATH searches for the original pip *after* it searches for the Anaconda version.

Comment: How can I find the Binary of my original pip? when I do "which pip" in the terminal it shows "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip". I am not sure how to find the location of my original pip